# JSDom on Azure (Native Node.js modules)

Tags: node.js, azure, jsdom, contextify

I'm having trouble getting a nodejs app which relies on JSDom to work on Azure due to it depending on a native module - [Contextify](https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify), I understand Azure does not provide compilation for native modules.

However according to [Azure documentation](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/common-tasks/working-with-node-modules/)

> Since Windows Azure Cloud Services rely on the node_modules folder being deployed as part of the application, any native module included as part of the installed modules should work in a cloud service as long as it was installed and compiled on a Windows development system.

It all works fine on my dev box as it's compiled during npm install, what I don't understand is why it isn't working on Azure as I am providing the compiled version? If it works on my windows dev box the compilation is clearly successful. I deploy to azure form a local git repository so I'm wondering if the compiled files are being left out when I commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: the latest Azure release (specifically, the Mobile Services backend) supports arbitrary NPM modules - [See the section on Mobile Services: NPM Module Support](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/06/14/windows-azure-major-updates-for-mobile-backend-development.aspx)

From the JSDom docs on the npm:

> Unfortunately, doing this kind of magic requires C++. And in Node.js, using C++ from JavaScript means using "native modules." Native modules are compiled at installation time so that they work precisely for your machine; that is, you don't download a contextify binary from npm, but instead build one locally after downloading the source from npm.

https://npmjs.org/package/jsdom#contextify

Since your "native modules" don't have the same signature as whatever machine in azure's "native module" would be signed, it doesn't load.